# Xcode 8 - Memory debugger doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, memory, xcode8

I'm using Xcode 8 with Swift 3 to develop my app, but I noticed the Memory Debugger isn't working for some reason. Here the screenshot : [image: xcode 8 memory debugger]
Do you know why? Is there something new I missed?

Comment: Is your target an iOS 9 device?

Comment: No, my iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 10.0.1

Comment: Found why : I had NSZombie enabled and this cause the debugger to not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the idea to check if NSZombie was enabled and yes, it was. Disable it make everything works.